# Flexible time based completitionPredicate in aggregator

Tags: apache-camel

I have a problem with Aggregator2 component. I use aggregation strategy that joins incoming messages into a list with expression property to specify date field which determines which messages should be joined together.

I need some completitionPredicate which will use some `cron` expression and some date field to decide when messages should be flushed.

The problem is that completitionPredicate is being checked when a message arrives, so if I already have aggregated list of messages that should be flushed it will be waiting till next message arrived.

Something that I need is some completitionPredicate which will be called every 5 sec. to check if messages can be flushed. How can I do that in camel?

This time will be calculated dynamically so I can't use completitionTimeout. How can I do this in camel?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot easily do this as you say the timeout is using fixed interval. However you can build a custom `AggregateController` which you can configure on the aggregator, and then build your own cron tasks that uses this controller to force completion of the in-progress group(s) of choice.

Comment: I try to find some usage example of this class to understand how it's working but I don't find something usefull. How should I use it? When methods `forceCompletionOfGroup(String key)` and `forceCompletionOfAllGroups()` are being invoked? How can I obtain aggregated groups from this controller?

Comment: From the AggregationRepository